# How do you interface with compiled Simulink model with Matlab?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have created a gui with app designer and have a compiled simulink model. How can I intereact with the model. How can this be done in realtime?

I know that you can use get_param and event listeners to interact with the model from app designer but it runs too slow for my needs and I would like it to all run as standalone.  Would you just use the eval() fuction?

What if the simulink model is doing something continously such as performing some computer vision algorithms (just an example) from a webcam live feed? I intend to compile the whole lot together, including the matlab code at a later time.

Comment: It depends on what code generation target you have used.  For instance, if it's the RSIM target then you modify the model inputs and parameters using .mat files, where as if it's a dll then you call the code like any other dll.

Comment: I will just be running it on a desktop PC.

Comment: Running on a desktop PC doesn't tell us what code generation target you are intending to use.